# how to get inverse of matrix in matlab

Tags: math, matlab

I'm using matlab.

I have matrix like

```
9 4 
5 7
```

Its inverse must be 
    k= [ 7  -4
        -5   9]

When I use inv matrix  at matlab

```
inv(k);
```

I get adouble matrix

Like (not true number)

```
 .37 -.32
-.32 .44
```

How can I get the inverse from the previous matrix?

```
 7 -4
-5  9
```

Comment: I think you might have a misunderstanding about what the inverse of a matrix is. Hint: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html

Comment: @user462715: why don't you ever accept answers? It's selfish and not very nice

Comment: Looks like you missed the `1/43` part in the solution

Answer (score 8):

The real question is why you need the inverse. Generally it's better to solve a system of equations. In MATLAB, you typically do that using [`\`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html). [INV](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/inv.html) has much poorer numerical performance than `\` or the underlying methods in `\` such as [QR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/qr.html) and [LU](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/lu.html).

Answer (score 7):

This is not the inverse; this is the inverse times the determinant.  So you need:

```
det(k) * inv(k)
```

Comment: thansk all i will try all this ?

Comment: Armen Tsirunyan : i dont understand you , srry i was offiline is is matlab

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what the inverse ought to be:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inv{{9,+4},+{5,+7}}